# Commutative Banach algebra and its maximal ideal space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-learning, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A:=C^{(n)}([0,1])$ be the set consisting of the n-times continuously differentiable complex-valued functions. Consider $A$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|:=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\dfrac{|f^{(k)}(t)|}{k!}}.
$$

> I want to show that $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra and find its maximal ideal space.

I know that the following holds:

- for all $f,g\in A$:  $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)=g(x)f(x)=(gf)(x)$;
- for all $f,g,h\in A$:  $((fg)h)(x)=(fg)(x)h(x)=g(x)f(x)h(x)=f(x)(gh)(x)=(f(gh))(x)$;
- for all $f,g,h\in A$: $(f(g+h))(x)=f(x)(g+h)(x)=f(x)(g(x)+h(x))=f(x)g(x)+f(x)h(x)=(fg)(x)+ (fh)(x)=(fg+fh)(x)$;
- hence $(g+h)f=gf+hf$;
- for all $f,g\in A,\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$: $(\alpha(fg))(x)=\alpha(fg)(x)=\alpha f(x)g(x)=(\alpha f)(x)g(x)=((\alpha f)g)(x)= f(x) \alpha g(x)=(f(\alpha g))(x)$;

Now,let $f,g\in A$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\|fg\|&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\dfrac{|(fg)^{(k)}(t)|}{k!}}\\
&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\dfrac{|\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} \cdot f^{(k-j)}(t)\cdot  g^{(j)}(t)|}{k!}}\\
&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\dfrac{|\sum_{j=0}^k {\dfrac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}} \cdot f^{(k-j)}(t)\cdot  g^{(j)}(t)|}{k!}}\\
&\leq \max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\dfrac{|f^{k-j}(t)g^k(t)|}{j!(k-j)!}}\\
&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\dfrac{|f^{k-j}(t)}{(k-j)!}\dfrac{g^k(t)|}{j!}}\\
&=?
\end{align}

Obviously, I want to show that $\|fg\|\leq\|f\|\|g\|$, **but I dont know how to do this. Any hints?**

Next, I want to find its maximal ideal space. I know that $f\equiv 1$ implies that $\|f\|=1$, so $A$ is unital. Hence, we working in a commutative unitial Banach algbra. Therefore, the kernel of a multiplicative linear functional on $A$ is a maximal ideal in $A$. **However, I can't find this kernel explicitly**

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo slipped in; a $k$ became $j$ for no reason. Fixing that, you're almost there, re showing it's a Banach algebra:

$$\begin{align}\dots=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{\dfrac{|f^{(k-j)}(t)}{(k-j)!}\dfrac{g^{(j)}(t)|}{j!}}
&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{|g^{(j)}(t)|}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\dfrac{|f^{(k-j)}(t)|}{(k-j)!}
\\&=\max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{|g^{(j)}(t)|}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\dfrac{|f^{(k)}(t)|}{k!}
\\&\le \max\limits_{0 \leq  t  \leq 1} \sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{|g^{(j)}(t)|}{j!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{|f^{(k)}(t)|}{k!}
\\&=||g||\,||f||.
\end{align}$$

The maximal ideal space is $[0,1]$ (that is, every complex homomorphism is evaluation at some point). You need to show that if $I$ is an ideal and for every $t\in[0,1]$ there exists $f\in A$ with $f(t)\ne 0$ then $I=A$. Look up the proof of the corresponding fact for $C([0,1])$; exactly the same argument works here.